# Adding a new language to Tesseract ios SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tesseract

I am able to compile the English version which is already in sample for tesseract but not able to add other language like `swe.traineddata`.

I'm doing like this

```
G8RecognitionOperation *operation = [[G8RecognitionOperation alloc] initWithLanguage:@"eng+swe"];
```

When adding this its giving this error but working fine with English.

```
Cube ERROR (CubeRecoContext::Load): unable to read cube language model params from /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D93B654A-1E46-4A34-9A83-95C6FC903085/*.app/tessdata/swe.cube.lm
Cube ERROR (CubeRecoContext::Create): unable to init CubeRecoContext object
init_cube_objects(true, &tessdata_manager):Error:Assert failed:in file tessedit.cpp, line 203
```

Comment: there are also other files associated to a language.u also have to add that

Answer (score 2):

The fact it does not work has to do with the engine mode. If you use the CubeOnly or TesseractCubeCombined, you need 'cube' files. Engine mode TesseractOnly works fine.

Comment: Unbelievable, simple yet when your looking deeper than you should, not so obvious. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you are missing some of files,I think so.Also check on Create Folder References.that helped me once.

Comment: Thanks @muku but i have only swe.trainedData which i have downloaded from google https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list?num=100&start=100. Can you please help me regarding the cube files.

Comment: extract that folder and then add it in to ur project

Comment: I have added the testdata folder which i have extracted for swedish text but the extracted folder contains only one file swe.traineddata unlike english which has 9 files in the testdata folder.

Comment: Can you tell me which other files we have to add.

Comment: create a folder in ur machine,drag that trained data in that folder.Now drag that folder and copy in to ur project and follow the steps as shown in image.Its working on ma end

Comment: I have done that before but its not working, i think we need more files for that langugae in testdata folder.

Comment: I have found a solution by changing the enginemode to tesseract only as there  no cube files there cube mode should be used.

Comment: @user1068810 Can you provide more detail re: your solution?

Comment: As there no cube files for language which i was using, mine was Swedish, therefore engineMode will take "G8OCREngineModeTesseractOnly. ".operation.tesseract.engineMode = G8OCREngineModeTesseractOnly; Otherwise it will crash, there should be cube files for language you are using. Hope this might help.